# How do I draw these tiles without them overlapping?

Tags: graphics, tiles

I want to make a map that is tiled, and I want to start the map with all grass.

I use this tile:

[image: grass tile]

When I display this tile and place another next to it I get the following result:

[image: Map overview]

How do I get it to be "flat?"

Comment: These tiles are designed to overlap each other while drawing.  You are going to need to do calculations to determine their draw orders, since you will want to draw the tiles in the back first.  So basically, you are not drawing your sprite at the correct position to make it "Flat".  If you want more help you will need to post some code.

Comment: @Jon: Good answer. You explained the problem source and solution. That is enough. GDSE is probably not the right place for code review. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not properly calculating the offset in the height from one tile to the next.  The offset needs to be set so that two tiles next to each other form a rectangle, like this:

[image]

Just adjust the height offset until there is no stair-stepping like you can see along the edges in your image.  For this particular tile it's 25 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the edges of the green tile are shadowed so that it looks more like a box than a flat diamond. If you can edit the tile just make the entire diamond the same color or at the very minimum make the shaded area the same color as the top.

Comment: That's not going to help the stairstepping along the edges.  The tiles need to actually be drawn in the right place before you consider fudging the art.